UX not shown the same way on iOS and Expo
I am using React Native to design the UX of a mobile app. The following screenshot shows how I want my screen to look like when visualized using Expo on my computer:
View from the computer
However, when I generate the IPA and view it on my iPad, the layout differs:
view from iPad
Margins appear, and the title and minutes remaining don't follow the desired placement. Here is the code from my screen:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView, useWindowDimensions, Dimensions, Alert, Modal, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { theme } from '../utils/theme';
import FontAwesome5 from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';

const LaunchedClassScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const { activities, targetFinishTime } = route.params;
  const [currentActivityIndex, setCurrentActivityIndex] = useState(0);
  const [startTime] = useState(Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)); // Track the start time, do not reset
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0);
  const [totalDuration, setTotalDuration] = useState(0);
  const [isCancelModalVisible, setIsCancelModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [estimatedFinishTime, setEstimatedFinishTime] = useState(0);
  const window = useWindowDimensions();
  const isLandscape = window.width > window.height;
  const activity = activities[currentActivityIndex];
  const nextActivity = currentActivityIndex < activities.length - 1 ? activities[currentActivityIndex + 1] : null;

  useEffect(() => {
    const totalActivitiesDuration = activities.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.Duration, 0);
    setTotalDuration(totalActivitiesDuration);

    const timerId = setInterval(() => {
      const currentTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
      const elapsedTime = currentTime - startTime;
      const remainingActivitiesDuration = activities.slice(currentActivityIndex).reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.Duration, 0);
      const newEFT = currentTime + remainingActivitiesDuration;

      setEstimatedFinishTime(newEFT);
      setTimer(elapsedTime);
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(timerId);
  }, [activities, currentActivityIndex, startTime, totalDuration]);

  const determineBarColor = () => estimatedFinishTime > targetFinishTime ? 'red' : 'green';
  const determineTextColor = () => estimatedFinishTime > targetFinishTime ? 'red' : 'black';
  const timeLeftText = () => {
    const currentTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    const timeLeftInSeconds = targetFinishTime - currentTime;
    const minutesLeft = Math.floor(timeLeftInSeconds / 60);
    return `${minutesLeft} mins left`;
  };
  const deltaTimeText = () => {
    const deltaTime = estimatedFinishTime - targetFinishTime;
    return deltaTime > 0 ? `${Math.ceil(deltaTime / 60)} mins over` : `${Math.abs(Math.floor(deltaTime / 60))} mins ahead`;
  };
  const formatTime = (totalSeconds) => {
    if (totalSeconds < 0) return ""; // Avoid negative time display
    const minutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60);
    const seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
    if (minutes > 0 && seconds > 0) {
      return `${minutes} mins ${seconds}`;
    } else if (minutes > 0) {
      return `${minutes} mins`;
    } else if (seconds > 0) {
      return `${seconds}`;
    } else {
      return "0 secs";
    }
  };
  const goToNextActivity = () => {
    if (currentActivityIndex < activities.length - 1) {
      setCurrentActivityIndex(currentActivityIndex + 1);
    }
  };
  const goToPreviousActivity = () => {
    if (currentActivityIndex > 0) {
      setCurrentActivityIndex(currentActivityIndex - 1);
    }
  };
  const completeClass = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Home');
  };
  const handleCancelClass = () => {
    Alert.alert(
      "Cancel Class",
      "Are you sure you want to cancel the class?",
      [
        { text: "No", style: "cancel" },
        {
          text: "Yes, cancel it",
          style: "destructive",
          onPress: () => {
            setIsCancelModalVisible(false);
            navigation.navigate('Home');
          },
        },
      ],
      { cancelable: true }
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = Dimensions.addEventListener('change', ({ window }) => {
      // Handle the orientation change logic here if needed
    });
    return () => subscription.remove();
  }, []);

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'column',
      backgroundColor: theme.colors.background,
    },
    mainSection: {
      flex: 3,
      padding: theme.spacing.medium,
    },
    header: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'space-between',
      alignItems: 'center',
      backgroundColor: theme.colors.background,
      marginTop: theme.spacing.medium,
      paddingRight: theme.spacing.medium,
    },
    activitiesLeftText: {
      fontSize: Math.min(window.width, window.height) * 0.05,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      color: theme.colors.primary,
    },
    activityDetails: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      paddingHorizontal: theme.spacing.medium,
      marginBottom: 0,
    },
    activityTitle: {
      fontSize: Math.min(window.width, window.height) * 0.07,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      color: theme.colors.primary,
      textAlign: 'center',
      flex: 1,
    },
    repetitionText: {
      fontSize: theme.fontSize.large,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      color: theme.colors.primary,
      textAlign: 'right',
      marginLeft: theme.spacing.medium,
    },
    activityImage: {
      width: '100%',
      height: window.height * 0.65,
      resizeMode: 'contain',
    },
    descriptionText: {
      fontSize: theme.fontSize.small,
      color: theme.colors.gray,
      textAlign: 'center',
      padding: theme.spacing.small,
    },
    footer: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'flex-start',
      alignItems: 'center',
      padding: theme.spacing.small,
      backgroundColor: theme.colors.backgroundLight,
    },
    backButton: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      alignItems: 'center',
      paddingVertical: theme.spacing.small,
      paddingHorizontal: theme.spacing.small,
    },
    backIcon: {
      fontSize: theme.iconSize.small,
      color: theme.colors.primary,
    },
    backText: {
      fontSize: theme.fontSize.small,
      color: theme.colors.primary,
      marginLeft: theme.spacing.xsmall,
    },
    nextActivitySection: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: theme.colors.backgroundLight,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      padding: theme.spacing.medium,
      width: '100%',
      marginTop: theme.spacing.small,
    },
    nextText: {
      fontSize: theme.fontSize.medium,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      color: theme.colors.subtitle,
      marginBottom: theme.spacing.small,
    },
    nextActivityImage: {
      width: '80%',
      height: undefined,
      opacity: 0.5,
      aspectRatio: 4 / 3,
      resizeMode: 'contain',
    },
    nextActivityTitle: {
      fontSize: theme.fontSize.small,
      color: theme.colors.subtitle,
      marginBottom: theme.spacing.small,
    },
    completeButtonContainer: {
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      padding: theme.spacing.medium,
    },
    completeButton: {
      backgroundColor: theme.colors.primary,
      borderRadius: theme.borderRadius.medium,
      paddingVertical: theme.spacing.medium,
      paddingHorizontal: theme.spacing.large,
      elevation: 3,
    },
    completeButtonText: {
      color: theme.colors.white,
      fontSize: theme.fontSize.medium,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      textAlign: 'center',
    },
    progressContainer: {
      width: '100%',
      paddingHorizontal: 10,
      paddingBottom: 10,
      alignItems: 'center',
    },
    progressBar: {
      height: 20,
      backgroundColor: '#cccccc',
      position: 'relative',
    },
    progress: {
      height: '100%',
    },
    progressText: {
      width: '15%',
      textAlign: 'right',
      paddingLeft: 10,
    },
    centeredView: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: "center",
      alignItems: "center",
      marginTop: 22
    },
    modalView: {
      margin: 20,
      backgroundColor: "white",
      borderRadius: 20,
      padding: 35,
      alignItems: "center",
      shadowColor: "#000", 
      shadowOpacity: 0.25,
      shadowRadius: 4,
      elevation: 5,
    },
    modalButton: {
      borderRadius: 20,
      padding: 10,
      elevation: 2,
      flexDirection: 'row',
      alignItems: 'center',
    },
    modalCloseButton: {
      backgroundColor: "#2196F3",
    },
    textStyle: {
      color: "white",
      fontWeight: "bold",
      textAlign: "center",
    },
    modalText: {
      marginBottom: 15,
      textAlign: "center",
      marginLeft: 10,
    },
  });

  const calculateSegmentWidths = () => {
    const totalActivitiesDuration = activities.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.Duration, 0);
    return activities.map(activity => (activity.Duration / totalActivitiesDuration) * 100);
  };

  const renderTimeSegments = () => {
    const elapsedTime = Math.min(timer, totalDuration); // Ensure we don't exceed total duration
    const progress = Math.min(elapsedTime / totalDuration, 1);

    return (
      <View style={styles.progressContainer}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', width: '100%' }}>
          <View style={[styles.progressBar, { flex: 1 }]}>
            <View
              style={[
                styles.progress,
                {
                  width: `${progress * 100}%`,
                  backgroundColor: determineBarColor(),
                },
              ]}
            />
          </View>
          <Text style={[styles.progressText, { color: determineTextColor() }]}>
            {timeLeftText()}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };

  const renderActivitySegments = () => {
    const segmentWidths = calculateSegmentWidths();

    return (
      <View style={styles.progressContainer}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', width: '100%' }}>
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1, height: 20 }}>
            {segmentWidths.map((width, index) => (
              <View
                key={`activity-${index}`}
                style={{
                  width: `${width}%`,
                  height: '100%',
                  backgroundColor: index < currentActivityIndex ? determineBarColor() : '#cccccc',
                  marginRight: index < activities.length - 1 ? 2 : 0,
                }}
              />
            ))}
          </View>
          <Text style={[styles.progressText, { color: determineTextColor() }]}>
            {deltaTimeText()}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };

  const formatRepetitionAndTime = (repetitions, durationInSeconds) => {
    const duration = formatTime(durationInSeconds);
    if (repetitions && durationInSeconds) {
      return `${repetitions} times (${duration})`;
    } else if (repetitions) {
      return `${repetitions} times`;
    } else if (durationInSeconds) {
      return `${duration}`;
    }
    return '';
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Text style={styles.activitiesLeftText}>
              {activities.length - currentActivityIndex } LEFT
            </Text>
          </View>
          <FontAwesome5
            name="ellipsis-v"
            size={theme.iconSize.medium}
            color={theme.colors.black}
            onPress={() => setIsCancelModalVisible(true)}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 3, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <View style={styles.mainSection}>
            {activity && (
              <View>
                <View style={styles.activityDetails}>
                  <Text style={styles.activityTitle}>{activity.Name.toUpperCase()}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.repetitionText}>
                    {formatRepetitionAndTime(activity.Repetitions, activity.Duration)}
                  </Text>
                </View>
                <Image source={{ uri: activity.Picture }} style={styles.activityImage} />
                <Text style={styles.descriptionText}>{activity.StaffOnlyNotes}</Text>
              </View>
            )}
          </View>
          <View style={styles.nextActivitySection}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={goToNextActivity} style={styles.nextActivitySection}>
              {nextActivity && (
                <>
                  <Text style={styles.nextText}>NEXT</Text>
                  <Image source={{ uri: nextActivity.Picture }} style={styles.nextActivityImage} />
                  <Text style={styles.nextActivityTitle}>{nextActivity?.Name.toUpperCase()}</Text>
                </>
              )}
              {currentActivityIndex === activities.length - 1 && (
                <View style={styles.completeButtonContainer}>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={completeClass} style={styles.completeButton}>
                    <Text style={styles.completeButtonText}>COMPLETE CLASS</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              )}
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.progressContainer}>
          {renderTimeSegments()}
          {renderActivitySegments()}
        </View>
        <View style={styles.footer}>
          {currentActivityIndex > 0 && (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={goToPreviousActivity} style={styles.backButton}>
              <FontAwesome5 name="angle-left" style={styles.backIcon} />
              <Text style={styles.backText}>BACK</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        </View>
      </View>
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={isCancelModalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          setIsCancelModalVisible(!isCancelModalVisible);
        }}
      >
        <View style={styles.centeredView}>
          <View style={styles.modalView}>
            <Text style={styles.modalText}>Are you sure you want to cancel the class?</Text>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 20 }}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={[styles.modalButton, { backgroundColor: 'red', marginRight: 10 }]}
                onPress={handleCancelClass}
              >
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Yes, cancel it</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={[styles.modalButton, styles.modalCloseButton]}
                onPress={() => setIsCancelModalVisible(false)}
              >
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>No</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

export default LaunchedClassScreen;

I tried modifying the styles multiple times and I expected it to look the same on both Expo and the iPad, but the differences are still present.
